# viewPagerAdapter fragment NullPointerException on Floating Action Button onClick

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I am create a floating action button or FAB in Android that can tackle important actions. In our app we have a floating action menu with 3 menu items, each for sorting movie results by name, date and ratings. I am use the java comparator and override the compareTo method to compare Lhs and Rhs movie objects and return results of comparison.

But, when I press one of the menu, for example: sorting movie result by name, always appearing error java.lang.NullPointerException

what's the problem with my code ?

And java.lang.NullPointerException in this code :

```
Fragment mFragment = (Fragment) mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

And Logcat :

```
04-16 02:10:22.137    3410-3410/com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.activities.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:229)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4336)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17853)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

i have declare on top public class MainActivity :

```
private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;
```

what is wrong with my code?
please help me..:(

This is my code in MainActivity.java :

```
package com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.SortListener;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments.FragmentBoxOffice;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments.FragmentSearch;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments.FragmentUpcoming;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments.MyFragment;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.R;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.logging.L;

import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    public static final int MOVIES_SEARCH_RESULT = 0;
    public static final int MOVIES_HITS = 1;
    public static final int MOVIES_UPCOMING = 2;
    //tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by name
    private static final String TAG_SORT_NAME = "sortName";
    //tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by date
    private static final String TAG_SORT_DATE = "sortDate";
    //tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by ratings
    private static final String TAG_SORT_RATINGS = "sortRatings";
    private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        //mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // TAB TEXT
            //tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));

            // TAB ICON
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setIcon(adapter.getIcon(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

        // CircularFloatingActionMenu Button
        setupFAB();

    }

    private void setupFAB() {
        // CircularFloatingActionMenu Button
        //define the icon for the main floating action button
        ImageView iconActionButton = new ImageView(this);
        iconActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);


        // Create a button to attach the menu:
        //set the appropriate background for the main floating action button along with its icon
        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(iconActionButton)
                .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_red)
                .build();

        // Create menu items:
        //define the icons for the sub action buttons
        ImageView iconSortName = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_36dp);
        ImageView iconSortDate = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortDate.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_map_white_36dp);
        ImageView iconSortRatings = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortRatings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_directions_white_36dp);

        //set the background for all the sub buttons
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        itemBuilder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_sub_button_gray));

        //build the sub buttons
        SubActionButton buttonSortName = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortName).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortDate = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortDate).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortRatings = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortRatings).build();

        //to determine which button was clicked, set Tags on each button
        buttonSortName.setTag(TAG_SORT_NAME);
        buttonSortDate.setTag(TAG_SORT_DATE);
        buttonSortRatings.setTag(TAG_SORT_RATINGS);

        buttonSortName.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSortDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSortRatings.setOnClickListener(this);

        //add the sub buttons to the main floating action button
        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortName)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortDate)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortRatings)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Anda telah meng-Klik " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.navigate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.tabWithLibrary) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityUsingTabLibrary.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.vectorTestActivity) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, VectorTestActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab materialTab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(materialTab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment mFragment = (Fragment) mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        if (mFragment != null){

            if (mFragment instanceof SortListener){

                if (view.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_NAME)){
                    //L.t(this,"Submenu SortName Clicked");
                    ((SortListener) mFragment).onSortByName();
                }

                if (view.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_DATE)){
                    //L.t(this,"Submenu SortDate Clicked");
                    ((SortListener) mFragment).onSortByDate();
                }

                if (view.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_RATINGS)){
                    //L.t(this,"Submenu SortRatings Clicked");
                    ((SortListener) mFragment).onSortByRating();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            L.t(this, "Error Fragment Null");
        }


    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_36dp,
                R.drawable.ic_map_white_36dp,
                R.drawable.ic_directions_white_36dp};

        FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentManager = fm;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            //return MyFragment.getInstance(num);
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (num){
                case MOVIES_SEARCH_RESULT:
                    fragment = FragmentSearch.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case MOVIES_HITS:
                    fragment = FragmentBoxOffice.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case MOVIES_UPCOMING:
                    fragment = FragmentUpcoming.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3; // Jumlah TAB
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)[position];
        }

        private Drawable getIcon(int position) {
            return getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
        }
    }

}
```

Code MovieSorter.java :

```
package com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Created by Qferiz on 15/04/2015.
 */
public class MovieSorter {
    public void sortMoviesByName(ArrayList<Movie> movies){
        Collections.sort(movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                return lhs.getTitle().compareTo(rhs.getTitle());
            }
        });
    }

    public void sortMoviesByDate(ArrayList<Movie> movies){
        Collections.sort(movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                return lhs.getReleaseDateTheater().compareTo(rhs.getReleaseDateTheater());
            }
        });
    }

    public void sortMoviesByRating(ArrayList<Movie> movies){
        Collections.sort(movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                //return lhs.getReleaseDateTheater().compareTo(rhs.getReleaseDateTheater());
                int ratingLhs = lhs.getAudienceScore();
                int ratingRhs = rhs.getAudienceScore();
                if (ratingLhs < ratingRhs){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (ratingLhs > ratingRhs){
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Some codes of FragmentBoxOffice.java, methods :

```
@Override
    public void onSortByName() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort name Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByName(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSortByDate() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort Date Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByDate(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSortByRating() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort Rating Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByRating(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

This is full code in FragmentBoxOffice.java :

```
package com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.R;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.Constants;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.Movie;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.MovieSorter;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.MyApplication;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.SortListener;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.logging.L;
import com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.network.VolleySingleton;
import static com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.UrlEndpoints.*;
import static com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.*;
import static com.qferiz.qferiztrafficinfo.extras.Constants.*;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentBoxOffice#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentBoxOffice extends Fragment implements SortListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    public static final String URL_ROTTEN_TOMATOES_BOX_OFFICE =
            "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Movie> listMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private RecyclerView listMovieHits;
    private AdapterBoxOffice adapterBoxOffice;
    private TextView textVolleyError;
    private MovieSorter movieSorter;


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBoxOffice.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentBoxOffice newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentBoxOffice fragment = new FragmentBoxOffice();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static String getRequestUrl(int limit){
        //return URL_ROTTEN_TOMATOES_BOX_OFFICE+"?apikey="+ MyApplication.API_KEY_ROTTEN_TOMATOES+"&limit="+limit;
        return URL_BOX_OFFICE
                + URL_CHAR_QUESTION
                + URL_PARAM_API_KEY
                + MyApplication.API_KEY_ROTTEN_TOMATOES
                + URL_CHAR_AMEPERSAND
                + URL_PARAM_LIMIT + limit;

    }

    public FragmentBoxOffice() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        sendJsonRequest();

    }

    private void sendJsonRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getRequestUrl(30),
                (String)null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //L.t(getActivity(), response.toString());
                        textVolleyError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        listMovies = parseJSONResponse(response);
                        adapterBoxOffice.setMovieList(listMovies);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               //L.t(getActivity(), error.getMessage() + "");
                handleVolleyError(error);

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void handleVolleyError(VolleyError error) {
        textVolleyError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError){
            textVolleyError.setText(R.string.error_timeout);

        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError){
            //TODO:
            textVolleyError.setText(R.string.error_auth_failure);

        } else if (error instanceof ServerError){
            //TODO:
            textVolleyError.setText(R.string.error_auth_failure);

        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError){
            //TODO:
            textVolleyError.setText(R.string.error_network);

        } else if (error instanceof ParseError){
            //TODO:
            textVolleyError.setText(R.string.error_parser);

        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Movie> parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<Movie> listMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null && response.length() > 0){

            try {

                JSONArray arrayMovies = response.getJSONArray(KEY_MOVIES);
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayMovies.length(); i++){
                    long id = -1;
                    String title = Constants.NA;
                    String releaseDates = Constants.NA;
                    int audienceScore = -1;
                    String synopsis = Constants.NA;
                    String urlThumbnail = Constants.NA;

                    JSONObject currentMovies = arrayMovies.getJSONObject(i);

                    // get the id of the current movie
                    if (currentMovies.has(KEY_ID) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_ID)){
                        id = currentMovies.getLong(KEY_ID);
                    }


                    // get the title of the current movie
                    if (currentMovies.has(KEY_TITLE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_TITLE)) {
                        title = currentMovies.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    }

                    // get the release date of the current movie
                    if (currentMovies.has(KEY_RELEASE_DATES) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_RELEASE_DATES)) {
                        JSONObject objectReleaseDates = currentMovies.getJSONObject(KEY_RELEASE_DATES);

                        if (objectReleaseDates !=null && objectReleaseDates.has(KEY_THEATER)
                                && !objectReleaseDates.isNull(KEY_THEATER)) {
                            releaseDates = objectReleaseDates.getString(KEY_THEATER);
                        }
                    }

                    // get the audience score for the current movie
                    JSONObject objectRatings = currentMovies.getJSONObject(KEY_RATINGS);

                    if (objectRatings.has(KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_RATINGS)){
                        if (objectRatings != null && objectRatings.has(KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE)
                                && !objectRatings.isNull(KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE)){
                            audienceScore = objectRatings.getInt(KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE);
                        }
                    }

                    // get the synopsis for the current movie
                    if (currentMovies.has(KEY_SYNOPSIS) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_SYNOPSIS)) {
                        synopsis = currentMovies.getString(KEY_SYNOPSIS);
                    }

                    // get the posters & thumbnail for the current movie
                    if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POSTERS) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_POSTERS)) {
                        JSONObject objectPosters = currentMovies.getJSONObject(KEY_POSTERS);
                        if (objectPosters != null && objectPosters.has(KEY_THUMBNAIL)
                                && !objectPosters.isNull(KEY_THUMBNAIL)) {
                            urlThumbnail = objectPosters.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
                        }
                    }

                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setId(id);
                    movie.setTitle(title);
                    Date date = null;

                    try {
                          date = dateFormat.parse(releaseDates);
                    }catch (ParseException e){

                    }

                    movie.setReleaseDateTheater(date);
                    movie.setAudienceScore(audienceScore);
                    movie.setSynopsis(synopsis);
                    movie.setUrlThumbnail(urlThumbnail);

                    if (id != -1 && !title.equals(Constants.NA)){
                        listMovies.add(movie);
                    }
                }

                //L.T(getActivity(), listMovies.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e){

            }

            //L.t(getActivity(), listMovies.size() + " rows fetched");
        }

        L.t(getActivity(), listMovies.size() + " rows fetched");
        return listMovies;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box_office, container, false);
        textVolleyError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textVolleyError);
        listMovieHits = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listMoviesHits);
        listMovieHits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapterBoxOffice = new AdapterBoxOffice(getActivity());
        listMovieHits.setAdapter(adapterBoxOffice);
        sendJsonRequest();

        return view;

        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box_office, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSortByName() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort name Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByName(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSortByDate() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort Date Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByDate(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSortByRating() {
        //L.t(getActivity(),"Sort Rating Box Office");
        movieSorter.sortMoviesByRating(listMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity.java line 229 change:

```
Fragment mFragment = (Fragment) mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

To:

```
Fragment mFragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

And it should work properly.

Comment: To improve your answer, use code formatting http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and don't use greetings like 'Hello' or 'Regards'. Keep it as short but informative as possible.

Comment: Thank you code it works fine. I forgot to change the variable name of the adapter to mAdapter on TabHost:

// Add all the tabs to the TabHost
         for (int i = 0; i <mAdapter.getCount (); i ++) {
             // TAB ICON
             mTabHost.addTab (mTabHost.newTab (). setIcon (mAdapter.getIcon (i)). setTabListener (this));
         }